# Length of longest cycle in this graph

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

In the above graph, the blue line shows a cycle of length $84$, the remaining edges are
higlihtged in red. In total, the graph has $100$ vertices and $143$ edges.

- Is this the longest cycle in this graph ?

The graph has no hamilton cycle because deleting the vertices $8$ and $20$ splits the
graph into $3$ components. Deleting the vertices $1,5,8,13,20,22,25,37$ splits the
graph into $10$ components, so it contains not even a hamiltonian path.

- How can I get the length of the longest cycle ?

Comment: The easiest way would be to enter the graph into Sage math and call longest_cycle()

Comment: Sagemath is freely available to download or use through Sage cloud - https://cloud.sagemath.com/ In case you still do not wish to use it I can do it for you if you provide the edges of your graph in a .txr file

Comment: You can use it through you web browser by registering on the link, otherwise it is relatively messed up for windows users.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant a .txt file. A simple file that contains the edges in a format that is easy to parse  - say dimacs format.

Comment: btw, are you trying to find  small planar hypohamiltonian graphs? :)

Comment: I rather try to find a classification of graphs with a weaker condition : Not hypohamiltonian, but traceable with every vertex as a start-vertex and not hamiltonian. In the literature, I did not find any useful conditions for the property, that every vertex is starting vertex of some hamiltonian path.

Comment: Can Sage check this property ? Is there a name for this property ?

Comment: I suggest you check the documentation related to the graph theory module http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html

Answer (score 1):

The comments gave many resources for finding the longest cycle in such a graph.

This is (not) the longest cycle in a graph. I will give a counterexample of length 85.

> 1 > 12 > 13 > 14 > 5 > 6 > 7 > 8 > 18 > 19 > 20 > 30 > 40 > 50 > 60 > 70 > 80 > 90 > 100 > 99 > 98 > 97 > 96 > 95 > 94 > 93 > 84 > 85 > 86 > 87 > 88 > 89 > 79 > 69 > 68 > 78 > 67 > 77 > 76 > 75 > 74 > 64 > 65 > 66 > 56 > 57 > 58 > 48 > 39 > 38 > 37 > 28 > 27 > 17 > 16 > 15 > 25 > 36 > 46 > 35 > 45 > 55 > 54 > 44 > 33 > 32 > 42 > 43 > 53 > 52 > 62 > 72 > 73 > 83 > 82 > 92 > 91 > 81 > 71 > 61 > 51 > 41 > 31 > 21 > 11 > 1

After running the longest cycle algorithm on Mathematica for quite some time, a longest cycle (of length 89) in the graph is as below:

> 1 >  2 >  3 >  4 >  5 >  6 >  7  > 8 >  18 > 19 > 20 > 30 > 40 > 50 > 60 > 70 > 80 > 90 > 100 > 
>   99 > 98 > 97 > 96 > 95 > 94 > 93 > 84 > 85 > 86 > 87 > 88 > 89 > 79 > 69 > 68 > 78 > 
>   67 > 77 > 76 > 75 > 74 > 64 > 65 > 66 > 56 > 57 > 58 > 48 > 39 > 38 > 37 > 28 > 27 > 
>   17 > 16 > 15 > 25 > 36 > 46 > 35 > 45 > 55 > 54 > 44 > 33 > 24 > 13 > 23 > 22 > 32 > 
>   42 > 43 > 53 > 52 > 62 > 72 > 73 > 83 > 82 > 92 > 91 > 81 > 71 > 61 > 51 > 41 > 31 > 
>   21 > 11 > 1

To answer your second question, the length of the longest cycle is also known as the graph circumference. That should give you a keyword to start exploring how one might get such a length. There are many ways to find the longest cycle, one of the simplest is a simple modification from the Hamiltonian cycle algorithm.

This is however an [NP-complete problem](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Computers-and-Intractability%3A-A-Guide-to-the-Theory-Garey-Johnson/bdede1e17c947540b50e6e2db9e8467ddc6e7336).

[Here](https://pastebin.com/P6tjbEXt) is the graph in the [adjlist](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/readwrite.adjlist.html) format should anyone wants to verify the above solution.

Comment: What Mathematica command computes longest cycle?

Comment: I don't think there's one that computes it directly. What I did was something like FindCycle[G,Infinity,All][-1]. This finds all possible cycles in the graph, and since the output is in increasing order, the last element is one of the longest.

Comment: How long did that take?  And did you try FindCycle[G,{90,100}]?

Comment: It took about 20 hours. I did FindCycle[G,{84.100}]. Why? Did you find a longer cycle?

Comment: No, 89 is the longest.  I just wondered about Mathematica performance.  Proving that there is nothing better than 89 by FindCycle[G,{90,100}] coming back empty might be much faster than 20 hours.

Comment: Incidentally, my Mathemtatica license expired yesterday and I can't test that out in the near future. I imagine, yes, it will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The length of the longest cycle is 89:[image]

Comment: Why is this the longest cycle?

Comment: I solved it optimally via dynamically added subtour elimination constraints, separately for each starting node.